Gunicorns cant assing command to workers
I work on notification server that integrated the Openstack. In this service there is api service that has multiple process. this processes executed by the gunicorn. Below code is content of the api.service file:
[Service]
Environment="oslo_config_file=/etc/safir_notification/safir_notification.conf"
Environment="config_base_path=/etc/safir_notification/"
ExecReload = /usr/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutStopSec = 300
KillMode = process
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /etc/safir_notification/gunicorn.py safir_notification.main:asgi_app --env oslo_config_file=/etc/safir_notification/safir_notification.conf --env config_base_path=/etc/safir_notification/
User = stack

Even if api service is active noone of the processes could execute the ExecStart command.

In a correct scenario status of the api.service should shown like this

I cant define error. how to define error or how to solve this problem?
